# Access select value with Select Case statement Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to know if it possible to assign the selected case string value with a Select Case statement to a variable. This way I would be able to do a VLookup with the string. I want to do this because I have way too many cases to take in consideration, and I want to update an other cell as fast as possible. Otherwise I have to reselect the cell after choosing from the drop list to do so.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Rref As Integer
Dim StrRef As String
Dim val As String

Set myrange = Worksheets("Feuil2").Range("E11:F54")
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I:I")) Is Nothing Then

Select Case Range(Target.Address)
Case Is <> ""

Rref = Target.Row
StrRef = Case.value  'Not working and would like to now the right command

Cells(Rref, 8).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(StrRef, myrange, 2, False)

End Select
End If

End Sub
```

[image: Image for detailed explanations]

Comment: Here you go @BigBen

Comment: Check if `Target` is one cell to use its value in a vlookup, but you're looking for `StrRef = Target.Value`. Also `Rref` should be a `Long`, not `Integer`, and `Range(Target.Address)` is equivalent to `Target`.

Comment: If I do so, I have to reselect the cell after choosing from the drop list to access the target value, and I find it really inconvenient.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `Worksheet_Change` instead of `Worksheet_SelectionChange`?

Comment: I'll try it, but I am using SelectionChange  because I want to be able to change values of column 9 from a droplist in column 8 also. Basically, I'm doing this because Excel does not allowed two ways lookup

Comment: Maybe add a screenshot of your setup with some sample data? Not sure I understand what you want to do exactly.

Comment: So I have a number in column H witch correspond to a specific description in column I that I get with a lookup. So if someone only has access to the number they can select the right one from the drop list and column I will update itself. But if someone only knows the description, and not the number, I want them to be able to select the right description from a droplist in column I and then the column H would update itself with the right number.

Comment: That is helpful. It still sounds to me like you're looking for `Worksheet_Change`, which fires when the value in the droplist changes.

Comment: Perfect, I'll look into it. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Yup, you're right. It is working perfectly this way haha. Thank yoy